# Free(): invalid pointer in C program

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, free, c-strings, calloc

I am executing following C program and getting runtime error as "free():  Invalid Pointer"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

static void freeArgs(char** args);

int main()
{
    char** argv = calloc(4, 10);
    int  argc = 0;

    argv[argc++]="yogita";
    argv[argc++] ="negi";
    argv[argc] = NULL;
    freeArgs(argv);
    return 0;
}

static void freeArgs(char** args)
{
    char** af = args;
    for (; *af; af++)
        free(*af);
    free(args);
}
```

Can anyone suggest me the solution?

Comment: You never `malloc` (or `callor` or `realloc`) the pointers in `argv`. Yet you pass them to `free`?

Comment: Also, what do you think will happen if `sizeof(char *) != 4` (like on a typical 64-bit system)?

Comment: Nevermind my close vote, bad duplicate. I can't be bothered to find a better one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
free(*af);
```

tries to free memory that was not allocated through `malloc`/`calloc`:

```
argv[argc++]="yogita";
```

`"yogita"` is a string literal, thus not dynamically allocated. You can't free its memory.

Answer (score 3):

This call

```
char** argv = calloc(4, 10);
```

(Note:it seems you mean

```
char** argv = calloc( 4, sizeof( char * ) );
```

end note)

with the magic number `10` allocates dynamically only one extent of memory of the size `4 * 10` that is equal to `40`. So you need to call the function `free` only one time for the allocated extent. That is how many times `malloc` or `calloc` was called the same number of times `free` should be called.

I suspect that you meant something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void freeArgs( char **args )
{
    char **af = args;
    
    while ( *af ) free( *af++ );
    
    free( args );
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 4, LEN = 10 };
    char **argv = calloc( N, sizeof( char * ) );
    
    size_t  argc = 0;
    
    argv[argc] = malloc( LEN * sizeof( char ) );
    strcpy( argv[argc++], "yogita" );
    
    argv[argc] = malloc( LEN * sizeof( char ) );
    strcpy( argv[argc++], "negi" );
    
    freeArgs( argv );
    
    return 0;
}
```